# How to use linked_scroll_controller with Flutter bloc state management

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview, state-management, flutter-bloc

In my flutter application I want to create a timetable widget which will scroll horizontally and vertically with corresponding heading. The timetable should have 'Day' as horizontal heading and 'Period' as vertical heading.I used [linked_scroll_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/linked_scroll_controller) to achieve this. Here I am used FutureBuilder to get data, which I need to replace with flutter bloc state management system. Below is my code

```
import 'package:linked_scroll_controller/linked_scroll_controller.dart';
import '../../time_table.dart';

class MyTimeTable extends StatelessWidget {
final SchoolClass selClass;

MyTimeTable({Key? key, required this.selClass}) : super(key: key);

late LinkedScrollControllerGroup _horizontalControllersGroup;
late ScrollController _horizontalBody;
late ScrollController _horizontalHeader;

late LinkedScrollControllerGroup _verticalControllersGroup;
late ScrollController _verticalBody;
late ScrollController _verticalHeader;

List<dynamic>? periodList;
List<dynamic>? timeTableList;
final List<String> rowEntries = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday",];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MyApi myApi = MyApi();
    _horizontalControllersGroup = LinkedScrollControllerGroup();
    _horizontalBody = _horizontalControllersGroup.addAndGet();
    _horizontalHeader = _horizontalControllersGroup.addAndGet();
    _verticalControllersGroup = LinkedScrollControllerGroup();
    _verticalBody = _verticalControllersGroup.addAndGet();
    _verticalHeader = _verticalControllersGroup.addAndGet();

    PreferredSizeWidget sizedAppBar = SizedAppBar(screenHeight, title2);

    return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: sizedAppBar,
        body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5,top: 8,bottom: 2),
            child: FutureBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (ConnectionState.done == snapshot.connectionState) {
                periodList = snapshot.data['periodList'];
                timeTableList = snapshot.data['timeTableList'];
                return Column(
                    children: [
                    Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                            height: cellHeight,
                            width: cellWidth,
                            ...
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: Container(// horizontal day header
                            height: 65,
                            width: 400,
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                controller: _horizontalHeader,
                                child: HeaderContainer(rowEntries: rowEntries),
                            ),
                            ),
                        )
                        ],
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                        child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                            Container(// vertical period header
                                width: 100,
                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                controller: _verticalHeader,
                                child: ColumnContainer(
                                    colEntries: periodList!,
                                ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            Expanded( // data grid
                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                controller: _verticalBody,
                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    controller: _horizontalBody,
                                    child: BodyContainer(
                                    rowEntries: rowEntries,
                                    colEntries: periodList!,
                                    dataList: timeTableList!,
                                    ),
                                ),
                                ),
                            )
                            ],
                        ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    ],
                );
                } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
            },
            future: getPeriodTimetable(myApi),
            ),
        ),
        ),
    ),
    );
}

Future getPeriodTimetable(MyApi myApi) async {
    var result = await myApi.getPeriodTimeTable(selClass.id!);
    return result;
}
}

class ColumnContainer extends StatelessWidget { //pink  // vertical period header
final List<dynamic> colEntries;
const ColumnContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.colEntries,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int numberOfRows = colEntries.length;
    return Column(
    children: List.generate(
        numberOfRows,
            (i) {
        return Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 65,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange)), // white
            child: Center(child: Text(colEntries[i]['name'])),
        );
        },
    ),
    );
}
}

class HeaderContainer extends StatelessWidget { // yellow // horizontal day header
final List<String>? rowEntries;
const HeaderContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.rowEntries,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _numberOfColumns = rowEntries!.length;
    return Row(
    children: List.generate(
        _numberOfColumns,
            (i) {
        return Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 65,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple)),//white
            child: Center(child: Text(rowEntries![i])),
        );
        },
    ),
    );
}
}

class BodyContainer extends StatelessWidget { // data grid
final List<dynamic> colEntries;
final List<String> rowEntries;
final List<dynamic> dataList;
const BodyContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.colEntries,
    required this.rowEntries,
    required this.dataList,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _numberOfColumns = rowEntries.length;
    int _numberOfLines = colEntries.length;
    int itemCounter = 0;
    return Column(
    children: List.generate(_numberOfLines, (y) {
        return Row(
        children: List.generate(_numberOfColumns, (x) {
            TimeTable curItem = TimeTable.fromJson(dataList[itemCounter]);
            itemCounter++;
            return Stack(
            children: [
                getEachItem(curItem),
                Positioned(
                  child:showPopup(context,curItem),
                ),
            ],
            );
        }),
        );
    }),
    );
}

getEachItem(TimeTable curItem) {
    if(curItem.subjectId != null) {
    return TableCell(item: curItem.subjectId!.name!);
    } else {
    return TableCell(item: 'Free');
    }
}

showPopup(BuildContext context, TimeTable curItem) {
    return PopupMenuButton(
    itemBuilder: (context) => _buildPopupMenuItem(curItem),
    onSelected: (dynamic value){
        if(value == 'add') {
        dialogBoxAddSubject(context);
        } else {  // edit
        dialogBoxEditSubject(context,curItem);
        }
    },
    );
  }

}
```

below is my bloc code :

```
class ClassBloc extends Bloc<ClassEvent, ClassState> {
final MyApi myApi;

ClassBloc({required this.myApi}) : super(ClassInitial()) {
    
    on<FetchPeriodTimeTable>((event, emit) async {
    var result = await myApi.getPeriodTimeTable(event.classId);
    List<dynamic> periodList = [];
    periodList = result['periodList'];
    List<dynamic> timeTableList = [];
    timeTableList = result['timeTableList'];
    emit(PeriodTimeTableList(item1MultiList: periodList,item2MultiList: timeTableList));
    });
}

Future<void> updateTimeTable(TimeTable timeTable) async {
    try {   // to save add/edit function and update the list
    var result = await myApi.updateTimeTable(timeTable);
    if(result['status'] == 1) {
        List<dynamic> periodList = [];
        periodList = result['periodList'];
        List<dynamic> timeTableList = [];
        timeTableList = result['timeTableList'];
        emit(const TimeTableCreated());
        emit(PeriodTimeTableList(item1MultiList: periodList,item2MultiList: timeTableList));
    } else if(result['index'] == 2) {
        emit(const TimeTableNotCreated());
    } else {
        emit(const ErrorDialog(title: 'Sorry',message: 'Something went wrong'));
    }
    } catch (error) {
    emit(const ErrorDialog(title: 'Sorry',message: 'Something went wrong'));
    }
}
}

@immutable
abstract class ClassEvent {}

class ClassInitialEvent extends ClassEvent {}

class FetchPeriodTimeTable extends ClassEvent {
final int classId;

FetchClassPeriodTermTimeTable(this.classId);
}

@immutable
abstract class ClassState {
const ClassState();
}

class ClassInitial extends ClassState {}

class TimeTableCreated extends ClassState {
const TimeTableCreated();
}

class TimeTableNotCreated extends ClassState {

const TimeTableNotCreated();
}

class ErrorDialog extends ClassState {
final String title;
final String message;

const ErrorDialog({required this.title,required this.message});
}

class PeriodTimeTableList extends ClassState {
final List<dynamic> item1MultiList;
final List<dynamic> item2MultiList;

const PeriodTimeTableList({required this.item1MultiList,required this.item2MultiList});
}
```

Please help me to use ClassBloc in my MyTimeTable class, so that I can list,add,update timetable easily in my app.

Comment: Hey! You should go through the segmented state pattern workshop here to make your bloc state easier to work with. Once you've done this, let me know. I cannot provide a comprehensive answer(time constraint) but I can certainly guide you.
https://dartpad.dev/workshops.html?webserver=https://dartpad-ws-segmented-state.web.app#Step1

Comment: @happy-san don't need a complete code, just guide me to sort the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75544897/flutter-bloc-linkedscrollposition-cannot-change-controllers-once-created

Answer (score 2):

Please check out [RepositoryProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/RepositoryProvider-class.html) and [BlocProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocProvider-class.html) from the [bloc package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc).

Use a `RepositoryProvider` to provide `MyApi` and a `BlocProvider` to provide `ClassBloc` to all widgets below in the subtree.

You can then retrieve your bloc (or watch it in the build method) and your api class where you need it, e. g. call a method on it:

```
context.read<ClassBloc>().updateTimeTable(timetable);
```

A call to `watch` in your build method automatically rebuilds your widget when the bloc state changes:

```java
final classBloc = context.watch<ClassBloc>();
```